# Diferença entre as funções mysql_connect() e mysqli_connect() em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Queria saber qual é a diferença entre as duas e qual é a melhor para se usar.

```
$x= mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$y= mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
```

Algumas delas é melhor ou mais recente que a outra? Se é mais recente qual é a vantagem de usar a função X ao invés da função Y?

Comment: [*Resposta*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/13412)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Além dos pontos citados nas demais respostas sobre as vantagens do mysqli:

- Interface de orientação há objetos (Object-oriented interface)
- Suporte para *Prepared Statements*
- Suporte para multiplos *Statements*
- Suporte para transações (*Transactions*)
- Melhoria no capacidade de depuração
- Suporte para servidor embarcado

Também é preciso notar que as funções `mysql_` não recebem mais atualizações, como correções e melhorias e este é o ponto vital para você não usar mais o `mysql_`, pois no futuro breve ele deixará de existir para as novas versões do PHP.

Em outras palavras, se você continuar a funções `mysql_`, duas situações podem acontecer com seus projetos:

1. Podem haver falhas na segurança da API `mysql_` ou bugs.
2. Quando a API `mysql_` for desativada, os seus scripts irão parar de funcionar, o que irá lhe causar muita dor de cabeça, pois você terá que refazer vários códigos.

Note que mysqli significa *MySQL Improved* em Portugues, seria algo como *Mysql melhorado*, fazendo referencia a API e não ao sistema de banco de dados.

Answer (score 8):

Esta é a mais recente e mais recomendada, a `mysql_connect` esta descontinuada, sendo a  `mysqli_connect` a mais nova e se utiliza de orientação a objetos, prepared statements, suporta múltiplos statements, suporte a transação possui melhor praticidade para se depurar:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Answer (score 7):

Mysqli é mais recente e tem suporte para features que o outro não tem, como prepared statements, multiple statements e transacções.

Deve usar o MySQLi.

Para mais esclarecimentos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php

Answer (score 5):

As funções da biblioteca MySQLi são mais novas e mais complexas, permitindo assim você executar stored procedures, functions e outros comandos que com a biblioteca MySQL não eram possíveis.

Prefira utilizar as funções `mysqli_*`