# strpos() está encerrando o while quando verdadeiro

Tags: php

Faço um loop de uma consulta. Verifico se o valor de cada registro contém dentro de uma string qualquer (no caso $mensagem). O problema é que, quando o valor é encontrado, nesse caso dentro do **ELSE**, o while é encerrado por algum motivo. Eu preciso que a verificação continue a ser feita em todos os registros, até o fim dos registros.

```
$query = "select id, id_usuario texto from palavra";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($palavras = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $valor = $palavras["texto"];
   $iduser = $palavras["id_usuario"];

   if(!strpos(strtolower($mensagem), strtolower($valor))) {
      echo " não.<BR>";
   } else {
      echo " sim.<BR>";

     $query = "select nome from usuario where id = $iduser";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
     $user_dados = mysql_fetch_row($result);

   }

}
```

Se tiro a consulta interna, o loop continua normal, como esperado. Mas preciso da consulta.

Comment: Seu código parece ter um problema mas ele não encerra o while, qual é o código real do else? o ideal é usar operador `===` para fazer a comparação

Comment: @rray Testei aqui e dessa forma o loop continua normal. Vou editar o código, o "else" tem mais coisas...

Comment: Eu entendi agora haha xD para quebrar um loop use o `break`

Comment: @rray Você estava certo, a ideia é fazer continuar mesmo, e não parar o loop. Arrumei lá.

Comment: Tbm vou alterar minha resposta ...

Comment: Calma ai, vc acertou o código mas o texto da pergunta não com os últimos comentários, pode editar a pergunta e clarificar.

Comment: O loop precisa continuar, e não parar após achar a primeira ocorrência.

Comment: Ok, o show continua :D

Comment: coloque: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` deve ter um erro na segunda consulta e no while por causa do reaproveitamento de `$result`

Comment: @rray vc matou a charada! O reaproveitamento do $result está com problema. A consulta interna alterei para $result2 e funcionou, o loop continuou.

Comment: Parece que nem leu e nem tentou o que passei na minha resposta, se tivesse testado o `ini_set` e o `error_reporting` teria chegado ao problema, pois como eu disse na resposta `provavelmente é algum erro no uso de mysql_fetch_array ou na sua query ou outra coisa próxima a isto`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu usei seus comandos para mostrar o erro. Não me retornou nenhum erro. Não era questão de erro ou sintaxe, mas de programação, basicamente sobrescrevendo a variável $result. Obrigado.

Comment: @DanielAccorsi ok entendi =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema parece acontecer na segunda consulta devido ao reaproveitamento da variável `$result` na segunda consulta mude ela de nome.

Para evitar falsos positivos com a função `strpos()` use o operador `===` assim ele compara o valor e o tipo. Sem ele se a string for encontrada na posição zero seu código será desviado para o bloco else de forma errada.

```
$query = "select id, id_usuario texto from palavra";
$result = mysql_query($query); //<--- primeira ocorrência

//aqui na segunda 'volta' do while $result já pode ser false ou não devolver as chaves texto e id_usuario
while($palavras = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   $valor = $palavras["texto"];

   if(strpos(strtolower($mensagem), strtolower($valor)) === false) {
      echo " não.<BR>";
   } else {

      $query = "select nome from usuario where id = $iduser";
      $result = mysql_query($query); //reatribução indevida.
      $user_dados = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Deve ser uma **exception** e os erros estão desligados por isto você não notou, ligue os erros do PHP, quando estiver em desenvolvimento, em produção uso `ini_set('display_errors', '0');`, provavelmente é algum erro no uso de `mysql_fetch_array` ou na sua query ou outra coisa próxima a isto.

Outro problema que pode ter ocorrido foi com a variável `$mensagem`, verifique se ela existe e se está no mesmo **"escopo"** do script que você citou.

Faça assim em desenvolvimento, coloque no topo do seu arquivo:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

Outra coisa `strpos` só retorna false se não encontrar nada, se fizer isto por exemplo:

```
strpos('abc', 'a');
```

Ele vai retornar zero e como `!` considera tanto `0`, quanto `false` quanto `NULL` quanto `''` (string vazia) então deve se usar assim:

```
   if (strpos(strtolower($mensagem), strtolower($valor)) === false) {
        echo " não.<BR>";
   } else {
        echo " sim.<BR>";

        $query = "select nome from usuario where id = $iduser";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $user_dados = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   }
```

Notei que usou strtolower, mas isso é dispensável se usar assim `stripos`:

```
   if (stripos($mensagem, $valor) === false) {
        echo " não.<BR>";
   } else {
        echo " sim.<BR>";

        $query = "select nome from usuario where id = $iduser";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $user_dados = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   }
```

Outra coisa importante é não usar mais a API antiga do PHP pra mysql, prefira PDO ou mysqli, leia:

- [Diferença entre as funções mysql_connect() e mysqli_connect() em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/3635)

Comment: Nem eu sei o que está certo, vc viu esse [comentario](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131333/strpos-est%C3%A1-encerrando-o-while-quando-verdadeiro#comment273264_131333) ? O.o

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema se deve ao fato do nosso amigo PHP interpretar o "**0**" da mesma forma que o "**false**". Então quando ele acha a substring no inicio da String ele retorna 0 (que o php também entende como false).

altere seu código para:

```
while($palavras = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $valor = $palavras["texto"];

   if(strpos(strtolower($mensagem), strtolower($valor)) === false) {
      echo " não.<BR>";
   } else {
      echo " sim.<BR>";
   }

}
```

Isso mesmo com 3 "**===**".

Comment: Não foi o mesmo que eu respondi?

Comment: É sim, quando eu comecei a responder você ainda não tinha postado, vi agora. :D