# Botão para excluir registro

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap, crud

Tenho uma página que mostra os cadastros realizados em um formulário.

Quando é necessário que um cadastro seja excluído, preciso acessar o phpMyAdmin, impedindo que qualquer um além de mim exclua o registro.

**O que eu queria:**

Queria fazer um botão que excluísse o registro posicionado ao lado, mas não sei exatamente onde colocar esse botão pra ele ficar na posição que eu quero.

**Matriz:**

```
<h1 style="
    text-align: center;
    height: 7;
    margin-top: 150;
"> Consulta de turmas </h1>
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from turmas");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:80;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

**Imagem da danada:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: 1° dica, troque a extensão de conexão com o bd, de mysql pra mysqli ou pdo, a extensão mysql está descontinuada e é totalmente desencorajado pela comunidade php continuar usando ela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar uma nova coluna em sua tabela com o link/botão dentro do while, segue abaixo seu código com a alteração / exemplo:

```
<h1 style="
    text-align: center;
    height: 7;
    margin-top: 150;
"> Consulta de turmas </h1>
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from turmas");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:80;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <thead><tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}
$table .= '<td>Ação</td></thead>';

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de exclusão
    $table .= '<td><a href="exemplo-excluir.php?id=xxx">Excluir</a></td>';

    $table .= '</tr>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

Comment: Muito bom! Então, cara, o único problema é que esse botão ta sendo gerado na parte de baixo do cadastro, e ele deveria ficar ali do ladinho. Sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Percebi que também estava faltando a coluna no título, alterei o código acima incluindo esta coluna e incluindo a tab thead, já que você está utilizando a tbody, se mesmo assim aparecer desconfigurado, é possível que seja algo do seu CSS que está gerando este comportamento.

Comment: Sugiro fortemente que leia: [**Não use a API antiga**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229256/14262) e ainda [**Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql) e mais ainda [**Diferença entre as funções mysql_connect() e mysqli_connect() em php**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/14262)

Comment: Por favor, se puderem ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229448/bot%C3%A3o-de-excluir-registro-n%C3%A3o-funciona