# Conectando o PHP com o banco MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Preciso de ajuda estou tentando conectar o meu arquivo PHP com o banco para poder realizar uma consulta e apresentar na tela os registros.

Código de conexão:

```
define('usuario_bd', 'root');
define('senha_bd', '');
define('nome_bd', 'loja');

mysql_connect('localhost/phpmyadmin', usuario_bd, senha_bd);
mysql_select_db(nome_bd);

$pesquisa = "SELECT * FROM nome";
$querybd = mysql_query($pesquisa);

while($correto = mysql_fetch_array($querybd)){
        echo $correto["nome"];
}
```

Meu servidor é o WampServer conexão com o phpMyAdmin.

Comment: coloque só localhost e o mysql está sendo descontinuado, utilize mysqli, Da algum erro?

Comment: Sim ocorreu os seguintes erros   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\pedemoca\model\conexao.php on line 7
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\pedemoca\model\conexao.php on line 7

Comment: Faça o Seguinte $conexao = mysql_connect('localhost', usuario_bd, senha_bd); e em mysql_select_db(nome_bd, $conexao); e tem mais isso foi removido no php 7 se estiver usando o 7 não funcionará terá que passar para o mysqli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PhpMyAdmin **não** é um banco de dados e o mysql **não** conecta via **HTTP**, o mysql por si só já é um protocolo próprio TCP.

### Diferença de Mysql e Phpmyadmin

leia isto:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)
- [Diferença entre as funções mysql_connect() e mysqli_connect() em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63331/3635)

### Não use a API antiga

As funções que começa com `mysql_` no prefixo são da **API antiga**, leia isto:

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

### Como usar a API MySqli para conectar com o banco Mysql

A variável `$host` deve conter apenas o HOST do teu servidor mysql, que **não tem nada haver com o Apache** e nem nada haver com HTTP:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = 'minhasenha';
$banco = 'meubanco';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($link));
    exit;
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM nome')) {

    /* Pegando os dados */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['nome'];
    }

    /* libera os resultados */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
    /*Trata o erro da query, se ocorrer*/
    printf('Erro na query: %s', mysqli_error($link));
    exit;
}

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

### Tratando erro na query:

Provavelmente a sua query esta errada, pelo que você comentou:

> Com o mysqli ocorre outro erro, no caso de Mysqli_fetch_array () espera que o parâmetro 1 seja mysqli_result, booleano dado – Otávio Guilherme

Conforme o exemplo que fiz, tem um if e um else:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM nome')) {
    ... SE OCORRER TUDO NORMAL ...
} else {
    ... SE TIVER UM ERRO NA QUERY ...
}
```

### UTF-8

Se não for usar UTF-8 **remova** esta parte:

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($link));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação detalhada agora estou mais atento nas diferenças e a maneira certa de utilizar e falar.

Comment: @OtávioGuilherme não se preocupe, é normal mesmo quem esta começando e até alguns com experiencia não entenderem o que é TCP e como funciona, por isto mesmo aquela pergunta que "linkei" eu mesmo respondi, é tipo um tutorial básico para quem esta começando ;)

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte se nada do que passei funcionar, ao que parece sua versão do php ja removeu o mysql_select_db então faça com o mysqli é simples desse modo

```
define('usuario_bd', 'root');
define('senha_bd', '');
define('nome_bd', 'loja');

$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', usuario_bd, senha_bd, nome_bd);
$retorno = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM nome");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno)) {             
 echo $row["nome"];
    }
```

Comment: Com o mysqli ocorre outro erro, no caso de Mysqli_fetch_array () espera que o parâmetro 1 seja mysqli_result, booleano dado

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, alternativamente você pode usar o PDO, que é um jeito mais consistente de utilizar vários banco de dados.

As funções mysql_* foram deprecadas á partir do PHP 7.0 se você ainda usa um versão antiga do PHP e precisar atualizar o PHP por algum motivo você terá problemas com esssas funções.

Você pode utilizar o trecho de código abaixo para se conectar com um banco de dados mysql.

```
try {
        $dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8", $host, $dbname);
        $connection = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


} catch (\PDOException $exc) {
     echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Abaixo um exemplo de busca com o PDO:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = :id");
        try {
            $statement->bindValue( ':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $statement->execute();


        $resultado = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
            throw new \Exception('Erro ao executar ' . $exc->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Deu certo, vou atualizar a minha maneira de utilizar o PHP e começa a utilizar o PDO, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Nestes links você pode obter mais informação de como trabalhar com o PDO. http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2011/12/tutorial-pdo-php-data-object/ http://rberaldo.com.br/pdo-mysql/

Answer (score -1):

Experimente editar sua linha "mysql_connect" para esta.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', usuario_bd, senha_bd);
```