# Botão de excluir registro não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, formulário, button

Tenho uma página de consulta que mostra os cadastros feitos no banco através de um formulário e um botão com a opção de excluir.

**Página da consulta:**

```
<h1 style="
    text-align: center;
    height: 7;
    margin-top: 150;
    margin-bottom:70;
"> Consulta de formações </h1>

<!--Filtro de busca-->
<form>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NOME">Nome: </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="NOME" placeholder="Nome do colaborador" name="NOME">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button href="acoes.php?acao=delete" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 22;">Buscar</button>
</form>
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from formacoes");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de exclusão
$table .= '<td><button href="deleteF.php" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button></td>
           <form method="post" action="deleteF.php">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="ID" VALUE="ID">
            </form>';
$table .= '</tr>';
```

}

```
//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

**deleteF.php:**

```
<?php

    $id = $_POST['ID'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `db_formacao`.`formacoes` WHERE ``formacoes`.`ID` = $id";
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Registro deletado!");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';
?>
```

**O treco:**

Se puderem me apontar o erro ou indicar uma forma melhor de fazer isso, ficaria feliz. :)

Comment: Deveria ter um input hidden com o valor do id e um form com `action` para delete, no sql tem um erro de digitação.

Comment: Mas onde eu colocaria esse action? Porque esse formulário que ta na pergunta é o formulário do campo de busca ali, não o formulário usado pra cadastrar as informações.

Comment: Para cada linha achada vc precisa de um novo form com a `action` `deleteF.php` que é o arquivo que faz o delete e também vai precisar de um campo hidden chamado `ID` para funcionar corretamente a linha `$id = $_POST['ID'];`

Comment: Vou editar mostrando como eu fiz, se puder dar uma olhada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro erro está nesse trecho da página de consulta:

```
//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    //eu tirei o código de dentro do for, agora ele vai gerar só um botão cada linha
    /*aqui você tem um button que serve como um submit, mas ele tem que estar dentro de um form para que envie o post. Então aqui eu mudei umas coisinhas*/
        $table .= '<td><form action="deleteF.php" method="post">'; //formulário com método post que vai para deleteF.php
        $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">'; //Nesse value tem que estar o ID do curso
        $table .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>'; //aqui está o seu botão
        $table .= '</form></td>'; //só fechando o form

    $table .= '</tr>';
}
```

Agora o seu arquivo deleteF.php tinha dois erros de digitação na query; formacoes está com 2 aspas e a variável $id tem que ser concatenada. ficaria assim:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `db_formacao`.`formacoes` WHERE `formacoes`.`ID` = " . $id;
```

Comment: 1- Você explica muito bem explicadinho.  2-Eu tirei o $table do while porque tava gerando um botão pra cada item do registro, fora isso, fiz as modificações recomendadas e ainda não tá excluindo. :/

Comment: mas se você não quer 1 botão para cada registro, vai ser um botão que exclui todos?

Comment: Essa linha aí é um registro, é "curso", então, quando for excluir, tem que excluir o curso inteiro, todos os itens.

Comment: então no input ID tem que estar o id do curso. Eu editei a resposta, dá uma olhada ;)

Comment: Ah, entendi! Então, fiz as alterações indicadas, mas ainda não ta funcionando. Olhei tudo e parece tudo certo, não to entendendo o porque. :(

Comment: OPA, DELETOU SIM! O erro era meu, eu esqueci de colocar o diretório do arquivo. --' kkkkkkkk Obrigada!

Comment: maravilha! que bom que resolveu :D