# Consulta mysql_query não retorna a coluna

Tags: php, mysql, query

Saudações a todos da comunidade. Estou passando por um problema estranho. Quando eu seleciono a sintaxe da consulta e colo no PHPMyAdmin, a consulta retorna todos os campos que eu quero. Mas quando coloco no código, não retorna valor algum.

Tenho uma tabela de usuários [usuarios] que contém a empresa à qual ele está lotado pelo campo [usuarios].[emp] que esta indexada com a tabela empresas [sjy_empresas] que contém um campo que à vincula à um grupo econômico [sjy_empresas].[grupo] que está indexado à tabela de grupos [sjy_grupo].

Eu preciso obter uma lista de campos da tabela bandeira [sjy_bandeiras].[bandeira] que estiverem contidas na tabela empresas [sjy_empresas].[bandeira] se estas empresas pertencerem ao grupo econômico [sjy_empresas].[grupo] a que o usuário pertence com base no campo empresas [usuários].[emp].

Já testei a variável $usuario e está funcionando.

Estou tentando executar esse código mas a consulta não retorna valor algum. Aonde está o erro?

```
    $title = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT `usuarios`.`usuario_id`, `sjy_grupo`.`id_grupo` FROM `sjy_grupo` INNER JOIN `sjy_empresas`  ON `sjy_grupo`.`id_grupo` = `sjy_empresas`.`grupo` INNER JOIN `usuarios` ON `sjy_empresas`.`id_empresa` = `usuarios`.`emp` WHERE `usuario_id` =  ? GROUP BY `usuarios`.`usuario_id`, `sjy_grupo`.`id_grupo` LIMIT 0, 1");

    $title->execute(array($usuario));
    $dados = $title->fetch();
    $grupo = $dados['id_grupo'];
    $query = "SELECT sjy_grupo.id_grupo, sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira
                    FROM sjy_bandeira INNER JOIN 
                    sjy_grupo INNER JOIN sjy_empresas ON sjy_grupo.id_grupo = sjy_empresas.grupo 
                    AND sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira = sjy_empresas.bandeira
                    WHERE id_grupo = $grupo
                    GROUP BY sjy_grupo.id_grupo, sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<option value='?id=724&band=". $fetch[0] . "'>" . $fetch[2] . "</option>";
    }
```

Comment: Esta misturando `mysql_` (API antiga do PHP e descontinuada) com mysqli (API nova do php), portanto nunca irá funcionar, ambas APIs não se comunicam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `mysql_query` e `mysql_fetch_array` pertencem a **API antiga** do PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Esta API antiga, cujo as funções começam com `mysql_` estão **descontinuadas** e foram removidas no PHP7.

Já o método que invocou `BD::conn()->prepare()` é provavelmente [`mysqli->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) que faz parte da **API nova** chamada *MySql**i*** do PHP (outra API **nova** é o PDO).

A funções `mysql_` **NÃO** se comunicam com as funções `mysqli_` (e nem no estilo OO: `mysqli->`), ou seja não tem como o seu código funcionar pois esta misturando duas APIs diferentes.

### Não use a API antiga

Como eu disse no começo, funções que começam com `mysql_xxxxx` são funções da API antiga, então não use porque elas foram removidas no PHP7 e no PHP5 ela já era considerada obsoleta, se no começo do teu código esta usando mysqli então basta ajustar tudo para mysqli, se esta usando o estilo orientado a objetos, então se mantenha nele, recomendo que leia a documentação e veja os exemplos:

- Escolhendo entre OO e procedural: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

> Leia mais em:
>
> - [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)
> - [Diferença entre as funções mysql_connect() e mysqli_connect() em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/3635)