# Exibir imagem armazenada em blob com PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

Armazenei uma imagem usando o campo `BLOB` do MySQL (`LONGBLOB`), porém não consigo exibir ela no `html`:

```
//Instanciando minha classe com PDO e fazendo um 
//SELECT de todos os dados da tabela, inclusive a imagem
<?php
   $DAO = new DAO();
   $result = $DAO->select("SELECT * FROM TB_ADVOGADOS ORDER BY DT_CREATED DESC", array());
?>
```

---

```
//O foreach da tabela com os dados e a imagem
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { 
   $createDate = new DateTime($row['DT_CREATED']); ?>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckhbox" /></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['TXT_NAME']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['NM_AGE']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['TXT_DESCRIPTION'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $createDate->format('d-m-Y') ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['PIC_IMAGE'] ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Eu acredito que precise formatar meu `$row['PIC_IMAGE']` para algo que reconheça essa string `BLOB` e encontrei alguns exemplos com `mysql_fetch_object`, mas nenhum com `PDO` que eu consiga utilizar. Só pra ajudar no entendimento, vou deixar abaixo a forma que usei para armazenar a imagem no banco:

```
<?php 
   $imageTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
   $imageType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
   $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    if($imageTmp != "none"){
       $fileManager = fopen($imageTmp, "rb");
       $conteudo = fread($fileManager, $imageSize);
       $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
       fclose($fileManager);
    }
    $DAO = new DAO();
    $result = $DAO->query("INSERT INTO TB_ADVOGADOS (ID_USER, TXT_NAME, NM_AGE, 
    TXT_DESCRIPTION, PIC_IMAGE) VALUES (:ID, :NAME, :AGE, :DESCRIPTION, :IMAGE)", 
    array(":ID"=> $idUser, ":NAME"=> $name, ":AGE"=> $age, 
    ":DESCRIPTION"=> $description, ":IMAGE"=> $conteudo));

?>
```

Alguma dica de como posso exibi-las?

**EDIT:**

Abaixo, segue o conteúdo da minha classe DAO:

```
<?php 

class DAO extends PDO {

private $conn;

public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meu_banco","usuario","senha");
}

private function setParams($statement, $parameters = array()){
    foreach($parameters as $key => $value){ 
        $this->setParam($statement, $key, $value);
    }   
}

private function setParam($statement, $key, $value){
    $statement->bindParam($key, $value);
}

public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);
    $this->setParams($stmt, $params);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}

public function select($rawQuery, $params = array()){
    $stmt = $this->query($rawQuery, $params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

}

?>
```

Comment: O conteudo de `$row['PIC_IMAGE']` não deveria estar dentro de uma `<img>` ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento possui duas formas que eu conheço de fazer isso, se eu fizesse uma pergunta e respostas das duas formas seria legal?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não poderia responder na pergunta da dup https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48325/3635? Se não me confirma que reabro esta ("martelo de ouro" pode reabrir perguntas de imediato).

Comment: Então @GuilhermeNascimento a pergunta parece que engloba um tipo, rapaz agora eu fiquei na duvida, porque o problema maior é que essa pergunta é aberta ... não sei sinceramente kkkk por isso que perguntei ...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A pergunta marcada como duplicada não ajudou no meu caso em particular :/ A programador da pergunta em questão utiliza mysqli, e não se adéqua ao meu caso. Exibir a imagem usando '<img>' funciona para mim, conforme a recomendação do rray, mas o problema parece estar na forma como a  imagem vem do banco. no var_dump($row['PIC_IMAGE']) é retornado um vetor vazio. Conseguimos reabrir a pergunta?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_object` é a API **"antiga"** do PHP e não tem nada haver com PDO, ou seja ambas APIs PDO e `mysql_fetch_object` "*não se comunicam"*, então este é o problema, se esta usando PDO, use apenas as funções dele e não misture com outras APIs porque não vai funcionar mesmo. Aparentemente foi o mesmo problema desta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233485/3635 ... Inclusive as funções da API antiga, que começam com o prefixo `mysql_` são obsoletas e foram removidas no PHP7, portanto não use a API antiga, pois ela já foi descontinuada faz muito tempo, use PDO e/ou mysqli.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o problema... aquele `addslashes()` não deveria estar no código. `mysql_fetch_object` faria o que?

Comment: @rray se essa classe DAO usar `prepared` então `addslashes` talvez nem seja necessário e pode ser outra coisa que esteja causando falha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento será não está gravando 'mascado'/incorreto o blob? por isso o problema só na hora de exibir?

Comment: @rray é possivel, ainda sim acho que o principal erro é que ele esta misturando PDO com a api antiga, como citei no comentário anterior, pode ser uma série de erros :/

Comment: Srs, O mysql_fetch_object realmente não tem ligação com meu problema. Na verdade, vi diversos exemplos de usuários que usam mysqli_fetch_array para tratar seu retorno do banco e conseguir exibir a imagem. Eu não utilizei ele em momento algum. Só foi um raciocínio meu muito mal explicado, por sinal hehe. De uma forma resumida, acredito precisar tratar meu retorno do banco de alguma forma para o html reconhecer aquela cadeia de caracteres em uma imagem, entendem?

Comment: Poste o conteudo da classe DAO, provavelmente o problema é **nela**. Fora que como eu disse, se estiver usando prepared o uso de `addslashes` pode estar truncando os dados.

Comment: @Csorgo primeiro, remova a parte do addslash, e segundo troque tudo isto: `$fileManager = fopen($imageTmp, "rb");
       $conteudo = fread($fileManager, $imageSize);
       $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
       fclose($fileManager);` por apenas isto `$conteudo = file_get_contents($imageTmp) or die('Erro ao pegar o upload');` e então tente fazer o upload de uma nova imagem e tente exibir ela com `var_dump($row['PIC_IMAGE']);`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz as alterações solicitadas, e agora eu tenho uma cadeia de caracteres gigantesca como essa (��Ś9l9{1t����j+L) em minha página. Parece que o html não está reconhecendo o que vem do banco.

Comment: @Csorgo esse é o novo arquivo que enviou depois de modificar para file_get_contents?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso mesmo. Os dois registros antigos ficaram com a moldura da tag img, porém sem carregar seu conteúdo interno.

Comment: @Csorgo ok, posta o conteudo do novo registro em um pastebin.com e me manda.