# Erro mysql_error() = "" e mysql_errno() = "0"

Tags: php, mysql

As vezes no sistema em que trabalho acontece de aparecer os seguintes erros `mysql_error() = ""` e `mysql_errno() = "0"`, mas isso acontece bem raramente .

meu código:

```
// Essa função está dentro de uma class do meu sistema 
// Exemplo : $sql = "Call procedure(1)" obs:no meu sistema trabalhamos com procedures

public function executa($sql){

    if($query = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn)){

       return $query;

    }else {

       echo mysql_error(); 
       echo "<hr>"; 
       echo mysql_errno(); 
       echo "<hr>"; 
       echo $sql; 
       die();

    }

}
```

Eu procurei a respeito e pelo que achei nas documentações do [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-errno.html) quando o `mysql_errno()` retorna 0 quer dizer que a query foi executada com sucesso, porém se ela foi executada com sucesso porque ela entrou no `else` da minha condicional ?

Comment: No php zero é convertido para false, logo cai no else. pq não muda não um pouco a estrutura. Sua procedure retorna valor?

Comment: @rray mas ai no caso foi executado com sucesso, tanto que executando no workbench funciona, e o retorno 0 da função `msql_errno()` significa que ocorreu tudo certo, e sim a procedure retorna os dados com o qual eu preencho a pagina e o estranho é que agora esta funcionando perfeitamente sem ter sido feito nenhuma alteração, eu vi gente no stackoverflow ingles que teve problemas parecidos onde `mysql_error() = “”` e `mysql_errno() = “0”`
mas as soluções deles não serviu para mim

Answer (score 1):

Se tiver multiplas conexões abertas é o que vai ocasionar a falha, pois ao invés deles pegarem o erro da conexão no handle em `$this->conn` vai pegar da ultima conexão aberta, então pode tentar isto:

```
   echo mysql_error($this->conn); 
   echo "<hr>"; 
   echo mysql_errno($this->conn);
```

### Funções com prefixo `MYSQL_` foram removidas no PHP7, atualize urgentemente

é preciso notar que as funções `mysql_` não recebem mais atualizações, como correções e melhorias e são consideradas obsoletas a quase uns 10 anos e este é o ponto vital para você não usar mais o `mysql_`, pois no futuro breve ele deixará de existir para as novas versões do PHP como mencionei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/3635

Você pode optar pelo PDO ou Mysqli (sua escolha):

Leia mais em: [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/3635)

Comment: Ok ,vou implementar isso no sistema mas como havia dito é uma situação bem atípica vai ser dificil testar. 
obs:está sendo criado uma versão atualizada do sistema, mas como ainda o antigo esta em produção ele está com os metodos `mysql_`, mas obrigado

Comment: não , apenas uma vez

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori talvez seja alguma falha ou confusão sua e acidentalmente mysql_connect esteja sendo executado duas vezes, sendo no mesmo script ou até outro script incluido que nada tem relação com este.

Comment: Eu procurei aqui no codigo, não achei ele sendo executado 2x e se fosse o caso esse meu problema não aconteceria sempre ?

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori Não porque dependeria do tipo de erro, então imagine que talvez `$query = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn)` falhe, devido a uma query errada que foi gerado por um "GET" ou "POST" mas já havia outra conexão em outro lugar (que veio depois), no momento que a query falha o mysql_error vai procurar o handler da ultima conexão e por isto retornou vazio. Resumindo, o erro pode ser qualquer coisa, pode ser algum dado invalido que esta sendo adicionado na query ou até mesmo alguma limitação imposta no servidor do banco, não dá para afirmar

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori vou aguardar o teste com a mudança que sugerir, me avisa se algo mudar ou não.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69080/discussion-between-vinicius-shiguemori-and-guilherme-nascimento).